Is A::member of vector of variant of A undefined behaviour?
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct A;

using B = std::variant<A>;

struct A {
    std::vector<B> v;
};

int main() {
    A a;
}

It compiles with GCC, clang and MSVC.
When I replace std::vector with std::optional it no longer works.
#include <variant>
#include <optional>

struct A;

using B = std::variant<A>;

struct A {
    std::optional<B> v;
};

int main() {
    A a;
}

clang + libstdc++:
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:40:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3416:7: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
 3416 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_rval_ref_t<_Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:372:5: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<A>' requested here
  372 |           (is_trivially_move_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:377:23: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_trivial_move_ctor' requested here
  377 |           _S_trivial_dtor && _S_trivial_move_ctor
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:759:45: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_trivial_move_assign' requested here
  759 |       _Move_assign_base<_Traits<_Types...>::_S_trivial_move_assign, _Types...>;
      |                                             ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:762:28: note: in instantiation of template type alias '_Move_assign_alias' requested here
  762 |     struct _Variant_base : _Move_assign_alias<_Types...>
      |                            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1362:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<A>' requested here
 1362 |     : private __detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types...>,
      |               ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:40:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:370:5: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<A>' requested here
  370 |           (is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:374:23: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_trivial_copy_ctor' requested here
  374 |           _S_trivial_dtor && _S_trivial_copy_ctor
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:705:45: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_trivial_copy_assign' requested here
  705 |       _Copy_assign_base<_Traits<_Types...>::_S_trivial_copy_assign, _Types...>;
      |                                             ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:708:32: note: in instantiation of template type alias '_Copy_assign_alias' requested here
  708 |     struct _Move_assign_base : _Copy_assign_alias<_Types...>
      |                                ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:762:28: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, A>' requested here
  762 |     struct _Variant_base : _Move_assign_alias<_Types...>
      |                            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1362:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<A>' requested here
 1362 |     : private __detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types...>,
      |               ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:276:8: error: field has incomplete type 'A'
  276 |         _Type _M_storage;
      |               ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:274:7: note: in instantiation of member class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Uninitialized<A>::(anonymous union at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:274:7)' requested here
  274 |       union {
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:434:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Uninitialized<A>' requested here
  434 |       _Uninitialized<_First> _M_first;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:516:41: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<false, A>' requested here
  516 |       _Variadic_union<false, _Types...> _M_u;
      |                                         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:581:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, A>' requested here
  581 |     struct _Copy_ctor_base : _Variant_storage_alias<_Types...>
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:618:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_ctor_base<false, A>' requested here
  618 |     struct _Move_ctor_base : _Copy_ctor_alias<_Types...>
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:656:32: note: (skipping 3 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
  656 |     struct _Copy_assign_base : _Move_ctor_alias<_Types...>
      |                                ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1362:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<A>' requested here
 1362 |     : private __detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types...>,
      |               ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:40:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3388:7: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
 3388 |     = __is_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:357:5: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_copy_constructible_v<A>' requested here
  357 |           (is_copy_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1364:43: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_copy_ctor' requested here
 1364 |         __detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types...>::_S_copy_ctor,
      |                                                  ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:40:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3391:7: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
 3391 |     = __is_constructible(_Tp, __add_rval_ref_t<_Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:359:5: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_move_constructible_v<A>' requested here
  359 |           (is_move_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1366:43: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<A>::_S_move_ctor' requested here
 1366 |         __detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types...>::_S_move_ctor,
      |                                                  ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:40:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3385:54: error: incomplete type 'A' used in type trait expression
 3385 |   inline constexpr bool is_default_constructible_v = __is_constructible(_Tp);
      |                                                      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1422:26: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_default_constructible_v<A>' requested here
 1422 |       variant() requires is_default_constructible_v<__to_type<0>> = default;
      |                          ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1422:26: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
 1422 |       variant() requires is_default_constructible_v<__to_type<0>> = default;
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/variant:1422:7: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for function 'variant' required here
 1422 |       variant() requires is_default_constructible_v<__to_type<0>> = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/type_traits:3413:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<A>' requested here
 3413 |     = __is_trivially_constructible(_Tp, __add_lval_ref_t<const _Tp>);
      |       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:506:12: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::variant<A>>' requested here
  506 |            bool = is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<_Tp>,
      |                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/optional:704:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for '_Optional_base<std::variant<A>>' required here
  704 |     : private _Optional_base<_Tp>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::optional<std::variant<A>>' requested here
    9 |     std::optional<B> v;
      |                      ^
<source>:8:8: note: definition of 'A' is not complete until the closing '}'
    8 | struct A {
      |        ^

I suppose it works because all std::vector implementations have their data on the heap. But that's not required by the standard, is it? If I'm not mistaken, it may be possible that some std::vector implementations do some kind of small data optimisation, making it similar to std::optional.

Vector cannot do small data optimization.

std::optional on the other hand cannot do dynamic allocations (thats the plus of std::optional, otherwise you could simply use a pointer instead of it)

it no longer works should be followed by the verbatim error message and include a questionable [mre] instead of showing the code that just works.

@NathanOliver Are there any other pitfalls, or is the code always correct?

Can you elaborate what is the actual problem you are trying to solve ? On the face of it it doesn't seem reasonable to have a member in A which is a vector of a variant of A itself. It would be interesting to see the use case.

@wohlstad why not? Its a perfectly fine [mre] with all "why the heck" stripped off

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it is indeed a proper [mre]. I was curious what is the use case of such a construct.

Are you missing #include <optional>?

std::variant requires complete type, inside class A, A is not yet complete.

@wohlstad It is in the data structures of my HTML parser. I just want to be sure that my implementation doesn't shoot me in the foot with a later standard that breaks ABI. When I wrote it, I didn't consider that variant needs all types to be complete. The vector has led to it compiling despite the recursion.

On the other hand, std::vector supports incomplete types.

the standard is very careful with each new revision to ensure compilers can maintain ABI compatibility. I wouldn't worry about ABI compatibility.

@bolov -- what do you mean? C++ Standard doesn't standardize ABI, it's upto compilers to decide.

@Benjamin Buch -- C+ Standard doesn't define ABI.

I know. However the standard and the standardeese people don't live in a bubble. For instance, even if the standard doesn't specify "how" to implement things,  they do work closely with all the major compiler vendors to ensure that what they define in the standard can actually be implemented correctly and efficiently in compilers. In the same manner they do collaborate with the all the major compiler vendors to ensure that the compilers can maintain ABI compatibility with each new standard.

There are exceptions of course. E.g. they standardised export template without an actual proof of implementation and then no compiler was able to implement it as specified (and they removed it from the standard since because of that). Another example is C++11 string which broke ABI compatibility. However they were aware that C++11 will break ABI compatibility (even if the standard doesn't specify ABI) and they worked with the compilers to ensure there is a viable upgrade path and interoperability between libraries using the old std::string and new C++11 code using std::string.

std::vector supportes incomplete types by C++17 26.3.11.1/3:

An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements (20.5.3.5.1). T shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of
vector is referenced.

The code is therefore always defined behaviour.
Many thanks to Jarod42 for mentioning this in the comments and putting me on the right track! Please correct me if my conclusion is wrong. I don't have much experience in how to answer language-lawyer questions. ;-)

Maybe important: This is only guaranteed since C++17. However, the reason this was added to C++17 specifically only for std::vector, std::list and std::forward_list is that the major implementations already worked that way anyway.
